# Trouble extracting data from Oracle db via C# (cshtml page)

Tags: c#, oracle, blob

I have an oracle db with a table that contains the following columns:

```
ID (Number)
WQUAL (ORDIMAGE)
PQUAL (ORDIMAGE)
ZQUAL (ORDIMAGE)
MEDIA_ID (NUMBER)
```

I am trying to pull out this data via a simple CSHTML page with the following code:

```
@using System.Data.OleDb;
  @{
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MEDIA.WORLD;User Id=ABC;Password=XYZ;";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DOWNLOADS WHERE ID = '1234'";
    myConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();   
        if (myReader.HasRows) {
            while (myReader.Read()) {
                @myReader["WQUAL"]
            }
        }
    myReader.Close();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

When I run this, I get an "Invalid column datatype" error.  I assume because the three ORDIMAGE columns.

I would like to understand is how to extract the info inside those three columns.

What I'm trying to do is run a simple dump of each row's `MEDIA_ID` and the three `ORDIMAGE` columns.  It seems like I cannot directly access what's inside those columns?  I was hoping for something like  `img src="@myReader["WQUAL"]"`

:)  Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that is indeed the issue by doing select id, media_id...?. plus I'm thinking ID = should be without single ticks

Comment: Yes. I did SELECT ID,MEDIA_ID and the query returns one row as expected.

Comment: If I run the query in SQL Developer, I see that those three ORDIMAGE columns contain BLOB data.  If I look in the BLOB, I see the image I'm after.  What I'm stuck on is how to get that image returned to the CSHTML page.